# How to limit number of times 'startElement()' gets called in SAX parser handler class?

Tags: java, xml, sax

I using SAX to parse XML & fetch number of elements from it.

In XML, there exists `<item>` tag number of times(easily > 50). But I want to fetch it only first 20.

Code of calling XMLHanlder:

```
XMLHandler handler = new XMLHandler();
xmlReader.setContentHandler(handler);
xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(in));
```

Code for XMLHandler:

```
public class XMLHanlder extends DefaultHandler {

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
        Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    ...
    }


    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
        throws SAXException {
    ...
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
    ...
    }
}
```

Is there any way that `startElement()/endElement()` does not get called more than 20 times.

If not is there any workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Just add some counter, start from 0 and `counter++` into `endElement`. Otherwise call `return;`

Comment: StAX might be an option as an alternative to SAX; allows you to just stop reading events.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SAX` does not offer any such functionality. A workaround is simply to use a counter:

```
public class XMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {

   private int counter = 0;

   @Override
   public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                                       Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

      if (counter < 20) {
            ...
      } else {
         return;
      }
    }

   @Override
   public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
                                                    throws SAXException {
      counter++;
      ....
   }
   ...
}
```

Optional here are the explicit assignment to `0` for the counter value (will take that value by default).

Comment: I was using this only .. but found this lil brute...was looking for something more implicit

Answer (score 1):

Add a counter as suggested by others. But you can then abort the parsing by throwing a SAXException from your ContentHandler. This will be passed back to the application that invoked parse(), which can catch the exception, inspect it to distinguish it from a genuine parsing error, and then continue normally.